# Most effient way to push all registers to stack in ARM64

Tags: assembly, arm, stack, arm64

I'm looking for a way to push all registers to the stack in arm64, for an ISR. My current code looks like this:

```
    stp x0, x1, [sp, #-16]!
    stp x2, x3, [sp, #-16]!
    stp x4, x5, [sp, #-16]!
    stp x6, x7, [sp, #-16]!
    stp x8, x9, [sp, #-16]!
    stp x10, x11, [sp, #-16]!
    stp x12, x13, [sp, #-16]!
    stp x14, x15, [sp, #-16]!
    stp x16, x17, [sp, #-16]!
    stp x18, x19, [sp, #-16]!
    stp x20, x21, [sp, #-16]!
    stp x22, x23, [sp, #-16]!
    stp x24, x25, [sp, #-16]!
    stp x26, x27, [sp, #-16]!
    stp x28, x29, [sp, #-16]!
    str x30, [sp, #-16]!

    stp q0, q1, [sp, #-32]!
    stp q2, q3, [sp, #-32]!
    stp q4, q5, [sp, #-32]!
    stp q6, q7, [sp, #-32]!
    stp q8, q9, [sp, #-32]!
    stp q10, q11, [sp, #-32]!
    stp q12, q13, [sp, #-32]!
    stp q14, q15, [sp, #-32]!
    stp q16, q17, [sp, #-32]!
    stp q18, q19, [sp, #-32]!
    stp q20, q21, [sp, #-32]!
    stp q22, q23, [sp, #-32]!
    stp q24, q25, [sp, #-32]!
    stp q26, q27, [sp, #-32]!
    stp q28, q29, [sp, #-32]!
    stp q30, q31, [sp, #-32]!

    mrs x0, FPCR
    mrs x1, FPSR
    str x0, [sp, #-16]!
    str x1, [sp, #-16]!

    bl  vector_irq

    ldr x0,  [sp, #16]!
    ldr x1,  [sp, #16]!
    msr FPCR, x0
    msr FPSR, x1

    ldp q30, q31, [sp, #32]!
    ldp q28, q29, [sp, #32]!
    ldp q26, q27, [sp, #32]!
    ldp q24, q25, [sp, #32]!
    ldp q22, q23, [sp, #32]!
    ldp q20, q21, [sp, #32]!
    ldp q18, q19, [sp, #32]!
    ldp q16, q17, [sp, #32]!
    ldp q14, q15, [sp, #32]!
    ldp q12, q13, [sp, #32]!
    ldp q10, q11, [sp, #32]!
    ldp q8, q9, [sp, #32]!
    ldp q6, q7, [sp, #32]!
    ldp q4, q5, [sp, #32]!
    ldp q2, q3, [sp, #32]!
    ldp q0, q1, [sp, #32]!

    ldr x30, [sp, #16]!
    ldp x28, x29, [sp, #16]!
    ldp x26, x27, [sp, #16]!
    ldp x24, x25, [sp, #16]!
    ldp x22, x23, [sp, #16]!
    ldp x20, x21, [sp, #16]!
    ldp x18, x19, [sp, #16]!
    ldp x16, x17, [sp, #16]!
    ldp x14, x15, [sp, #16]!
    ldp x12, x13, [sp, #16]!
    ldp x10, x11, [sp, #16]!
    ldp x8, x9, [sp, #16]!
    ldp x6, x7, [sp, #16]!
    ldp x4, x5, [sp, #16]!
    ldp x2, x3, [sp, #16]!
    ldp x0, x1, [sp, #16]!

    eret
```

(i.e. firstly push all general-purpose registers, then push all SIMD FP registers, branch to the correct vector and then pop everything back)

Is there a way to do this more efficiently? This interrupt runs very often and any piece of performance gain is nice to have.

Comment: Consider pushing only the registers you actually modify in your interrupt handler.

Comment: While I would love to do that, I _have_ to push all the registers to the stack, since I do not know what registers will be modified in the interrupt handler due to the way the code is written

Comment: Can you not at least skip saving x19 to x29, since those are callee-saved in ARM64?

Comment: @qwerty123443 Under these constraints, I suppose there is no other way than what you are already doing.  However, I doubt that this is really true.  How is it that the code can trash any register?  Why is that the case?

Comment: If the interrupt runs "very often", it's probably worth optimizing it to limit what registers it can clobber.  Unless it's already fast enough, in which case you can just keep spending cycles to save/restore everything.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that all the registers really need to be saved, as already mentioned in the comments.

With the general-purpose registers, no more than two can be written or loaded into memory at the same time, there is simply no instruction to do so. With the SIMD registers it is a little different: Using the instruction

```
ST4 { V0.2D, V1.2D, V2.2D, V3.2D }, [SP], #64
```

four consecutive SIMD-registers can be written at the same time. This causes the register values to be interleaved before they are placed on the stack. However, this should not be a problem as long as they are reloaded in the same way (using `LD4`) and not accessed in the meantime (otherwise you have to figure out where your values ended up). This reduces the code size and could also make it faster (see my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62734930/arm64-assembly-ldp-vs-ld4-execution-time)). This would replace the corresponding part in your code

```
    stp q0, q1, [sp, #-32]!
    // ...
    stp q30, q31, [sp, #-32]!
```

with the four lines

```
    st4 {  v0.2d,  v1.2d,  v2.2d,  v3.2d }, [sp], #64
    st4 {  v4.2d,  v5.2d,  v6.2d,  v7.2d }, [sp], #64
    st4 {  v8.2d,  v9.2d, v10.2d, v11.2d }, [sp], #64
    st4 { v12.2d, v13.2d, v14.2d, v15.2d }, [sp], #64
```

and analogously with `LD4`. Note that `ST4` only supports post-index, while you have always used pre-index. It would be the easiest to change this everywhere.

Comment: Read OPs question again.  He needs to save the general purpose registers for an interrupt handler.  It won't particularly help him to save some other registers instead.

Comment: The SIMD registers are also saved in OP's code, there under the names `q0` to `q31` instead of `v0.2d` to `v31.2d` (the name only indicates the type of access). I only commented on saving these registers, so it's only a partial answer but should address the question.

Comment: That makes sense.  Though note that `st4` permutes its arguments to convert from a SoA representation to an AoS representation.  You want `st1` for a direct store.